# Why am I suspended from chat?

Tags: support, chat

I just got suspended from chat for posting inappropriate content. The message was:

> Just restarted movies and tv

How is this inappropriate?

Comment: I thought you said [everone on PPCG gave up on raiding?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20843800#20843800)

Comment: I'm really impressed that even after [this whole debacle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252393/when-something-that-was-supposed-to-be-fun-became-not-fun/#252398) and like 10 different mods showing up in the PPCG chat room (not to mention all the normal users) that you still don't get why raiding is bad.

Comment: I'm not saying you still advocate raiding, but you should understand why this message is inappropriate by now.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Your words which are a part of the chat transcript are available for users to peruse, judge, flag, etc. If they believe your message was inappropriate it could be flagged after the fact.

Comment: Why didn't you include relevant details like this in your question? Personally I'm quite tired of this drama and if you're going to incite even more, I am not at all interested in caring about it. You acted in poor sportsmanship, your actions now have repercussions and instead of sitting it out for a day you're invoking even more.

Comment: [Revenge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revenge).

Answer (score 35):

My guess would be that movies and tv didn't want to be restarted.

Comment: Blame Stack Egg for everything bad today.

Comment: @bluefeet Seriously, I'm almost regretting visiting SE today.  Getting way too caught up in this.

Comment: @bluefeet - You know, I'm just going to come back tomorrow. I'm sure everything on the Internet will be well-behaved and very serious then.