# We liked StackEgg - let the fun continue!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, april-fools, stackegg

As [already said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252403/278654) by Jon Ericson:

> Tomorrow (or a bit later in your timezone), the game will be gone from the site.

So, I would like to request StackEgg to be available elsewhere. Is it possible to host the source code in GitHub? With that, we can *win the internet* three times:

1. Someone will likely host the game somewhere and invite us to play more.
2. Lonely players will be able to play alone.
3. We can dig into the code and learn a thing or two.

Comment: I agree! I really liked the game concept, I hope they will make the code available.

Comment: Also, make it as a mobile app, and I'm sold :)

Comment: As a game, it is soul-crushingly boring. As a puzzle to figure out how a simple engine works, it is somewhat entertaining. Upvoted because I would like to see the source.

Comment: I'll throw the core game logic wrapped in a console app onto Github when it's over (i.e. just the pure game, without voting, animation, etc.; decoupling the latter into a standalone thing would be too much work for a little fun thing).

Comment: @balpha since you mentioned "without animation", I hope the images can be salvaged (I know I can save the canvas image 1-by-1, but it's a bit tedious since it's always animating), since that's what I love about Stack Egg. But if it's impossible due to licensing, then that's okay.

Comment: @AndrewT. I hand-drew everything, so I don't assume licensing would be an issue. I'll look if I can find a good place to keep the animations.

Comment: It would at least be nice to see the final leaderboard now that it's over, be it only for just a few days. Does the non-obvious link just elude me or did it really just vanish without the possibility for checking the results of a game everyone took that serious?

Comment: @ChristianRau, The link is gone, but the address is still up. You can check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/stackegg/leaderboard). Anime & Manga won with 27 completed games followed by Code Golf with 21.

Comment: Has anybody hosted it yet?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's it, April 1st is over everywhere in the world :(

I have, as promised, put the game's core logic into a Github repo. You can find it at https://github.com/StackExchange/stackegg, if you want to check out exactly how what actions influenced the game.

If you just want to relive the animations, you can find all of them at http://stackexchange.github.io/stackegg/.

Comment: Yay! I was hoping that the frontend would become open-source too (so we could play with other people), but this is still going to be fun :D

Comment: @Doorknob Make your own frontend! You're a coder, right? ;-)

Comment: +1000! Awesome, second only to the Unicornify :D

Comment: @cky or better, submit a pull request

Comment: @Sklivvz Nah, I consider this a code dump, don't really want to maintain it as an open-source project. I'll make it MIT-licensed as soon as I get permission, though (that's just a formality), so fork away afterwards.

Comment: Did you calculate the optimal strategy for each round or am I going to have to do it myself?