# Play Unikong Forever

Tags: feature-request, april-fools, unikong

Can the game please be kept after today, even just as some hidden, super secret link?

Pretty please?

[image]

Comment: (+1) Yes, pretty pplease ^_^.   It reminded me of the Dave game from the 90's!

Comment: Kitten eyes, with knowledge of the author of said game - well played, well played.

Comment: @TimPost if the game came up on steam greenlight, i'd vote for it.

Comment: It's not like it is a change that will cause any noise to users that don't  want to see it again. Just put it somewhere on a "StackHistoria" page

Comment: Last year's April Fools was made open source, I don't see why this one wouldn't be as well.

Comment: Open source it! Last year: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252451/we-liked-stackegg-let-the-fun-continue). Related for this year: [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320262/will-unikong-be-open-sourced).

Comment: @SimonForsberg well only the core, no link to actual web page where you can play it. Still awesome, but I am greedy... :-)

Comment: My son keeps asking me to play, so for the sake of my productivity: please no! ;-)

Comment: @cybermonkey awesome, think it's worth an answer... though I'm not sure about the legal aspect, April Fools or not. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Added.

Comment: We plan to keep it around. It just runs off our CDN and is isolated from everything else we have, so it doesn't really cost us anything to keep it going. I'll update this post next week once we sort out a few things (I also want to open-source the code and whatnot).

Comment: Thanks @Adam that's ideal!

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ lol, I prefer a unicorn but guess you'd do just fine in the meantime... :P

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found from this [SO Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320238/will-unikong-be-available-after-april-1st/320241), you can play it from here:

> https://unikong.github.io/

And it runs super silky smooth no lag no nothing, just as we played on that day!

Update: Found the official link: http://stackexchange.github.io/unikong/

Comment: Huh, neat... any idea who put it there? Not familiar enough with GH.

Comment: @ShadowWizard From the associated [GitHub repo](https://github.com/unikong/unikong.github.io), it looks like it was [Alexander O'Mara](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara).

Comment: @Shadow9 could you please accept this answer? It has an official link, and the other one is broken, but this doesn't show first.

Comment: @Stormblessed I... totally forgot this is my own question! I saw the edit and noticed I already upvoted, but didn't bother to check who's the OP or the other answers. lol