# StackEgg is misspelt

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, april-fools, stackegg

I mean, that's not good to break the tendency of writing, for example, "Stack Exchange" or "Stack Overflow" or "Super User" or etc.

So. It should be. Untypoed! Why StackEgg, while it *must* be Stack Egg?

Even my auto-correction doesn't respect it.

Comment: Because it is called StackEgg. Don't argue or all the producers will come and wreck you...

Comment: [Stackagotchi](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252379/stackagotchi-strategery) would be a better name.

Comment: @Pyth wah, are they ogres?

Comment: It's Shrek 4! Or is it...

Comment: @Anna the reason is the below answer?:)

Comment: Yes, but also "this is what it's called, so it's by design".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

StackEgg is clearly a reference to digital pet games, specifically the Tamagotchi series.

Tamagotchi, as [Wikipedia points out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi), is a portmanteau combining the Japanese word "たまご" (tamago), which means "egg", and the English word "watch". Similiarly, consider StackEgg to be a portmanteau of Stack Exchange (stackexchange.com) + egg (a literal egg).

I'm pretty sure it's in reference to Tamagotchi since the look of the devices are uncannily similar.

Also, [Anna Lear has approved my theory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252441/stackegg-is-misspelt/252442#comment824529_252441):

> Yes, but also "this is what it's called, so it's by design".

[image]